# How to apply `Length` in all elements

Tags: functions, function-construction

I want to apply `Length` in each element from a list.
For example:

My list is: `{1,{2,3},{4,5,6}}`

How to apply `Length` in each element of this list?

```
Length[{1}]
Length[{2,3}]
Length[{4,5,6}]
```

I have tried to use `Thread`, but doesn't works:

```
In[235]:= Thread[Length[{1, {2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}]]

Out[235]= 3
```

The result that I want is some like:

```
1
2
3
```

Which is the number of elements in each element.

Comment: What in your opinion is the `Length` of `1`? You can use `Map`: `Map[Length, {1, {2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
If[AtomQ @ #, 1, Length @ #] & /@ {1, {2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}
```

> {1, 2, 3}

If the input list does not contain `{}` (thanks: @corey979), you can also use:

```
Length /@ {1, {2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}} /. 0 -> 1
(* or Map[Length]@{1, {2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}} /. 0 -> 1 *)
```

> {1, 2, 3}

Comment: Note that the first approach fails on `{1, {2, 3}, {}, {4, 5, 6}}`. The second, however, works well.

Comment: @corey979, very good point.

Answer (score 5):

Introduce `` Charting`padList `` to make a list for your element..

```
Length@*Charting`padList /@ {1, {2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}
```

> `{1, 2, 3}`

Comment: Brilliant. Care to elaborate more on ``Charting`padList``?

Answer (score 0):

A mildly adjusted version of the nice `Charting` answer by yode is to apply a list to each element and flatten:

```
Length@Flatten@List@#&/@{1, {2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}
```