# Creating a function that is a variant of Length

Tags: function-construction

I want to create a new function `nLength` that applies `Length`in each element from a list automatically. For example:

I have a list: `{1,{2,3},{4,5,6}}`

If I use `nLength`has to return:

```
nLength[{1,{2,3},{4,5,6}}]

{1,2,3}
```

Which is the number of elements in each element.

I have tried some like that, but doesn't works:

```
nLength[{n__}] := Map[Length, #]&n
```

Comment: Duplicate:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/190015/how-to-apply-length-in-all-elements

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply \`Length\` in all elements](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/190015/how-to-apply-length-in-all-elements)

Comment: Is not the same question. Now I want to create a new function using a pure function. Some in syntax (I guess) is wrong and I don't know where.

Comment: Your argument to `nLength` doesn't appear on the right side anywhere.  That said, you might want to consider what `nLength[{Log[2,3]}]` should return.

Comment: I edited the question adding the argument in the right side.

Comment: `nLength[{n__}] := Map[Length[#] &, {n}]` is what you're looking for.  By the way the first element is not a list, so it's length is 0.

Comment: You got it @QuantumDot. Thanks. Just one more question. How can I write using `/@`instead `Map`?

Comment: Wouldn't it be clearer and fewer keystrokes to avoid defining a new function and use `Length/@{1, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}}` since all the function does is call the built-in `Length` function?

Comment: Why is `Length[1] == 1`?

Comment: To write it using `/@` instead of `Map`, you would use  `nLength[{n__}] := Length[#]& /@ {n}`

Comment: @QuatumDot Wouldn,'t `nLength[a_List] := Length /@ a` be easier?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Yes, but that wouldn't have satisfied the requirement stated in the title of v2 of this post which was to use pure functions.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of no good reason for using a pure function in the implementation of your variant of `List`, but I do think your requirement that atoms should be treated as having length 1 is something that requires some thought.

Here is how I would do it.

```
Clear[helper, nLen]
helper[item_?AtomQ] := 1
helper[item_] := Length[item]
nLen[u_ /; Length[u] === 0] := 0
nLen[u_] := helper /@ u
```

Now some tests including looking at some edge cases.

```
nLen[{1, {2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}]
```

> `{1, 2, 3}`

```
nLen[foo[{}, {1}, bar[2, 3], quux[4, {a, b}, {}]]]
```

> `foo[0, 1, 2, 3]`

```
nLen[{}]
```

> `0`

```
nLen[f[]]
```

> `0`

Note that like `Length`, `nLen` works on expression with any head.

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[lENGTH]
lENGTH = Module[{s = 0}, ++s & /@ Map[List, Inactivate @ #, {-1}]; s] &;
```

**Examples:**

```
Grid[Prepend[{#, lENGTH@#, Length@#} & /@ {3, a, {}, {{}}, f[], a + b, a b c,
     f[1, aa, b, 3], {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3},{1, {2, {3, {4, {5}}}}},
     <|a -> 1, b -> 2|>, SparseArray[{{1, 1} -> 1, {10, 3} -> 2}], Rational[x, 3], y^4}, 
    {"expr", "lENGTH @ expr", "Length @ expr"}], Dividers -> All]
```

[image]